# Is it possible to use `assoc` and/or `ftype` with wildcard characters?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, file-association

I tried to use `assoc` together with a wildcard character something like this: `assoc .doc*` which hopefully would give me `docx` as well as `docm` as a result (and any other).

Unfortunately it's either [undocumented](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/assoc) or not possible (I "blindly" tried various characters like `*` etc.). If anyone knows has an idea for a workaround or a working solution, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows for Workgroups 3.11 programs were listed against extensions.

In Windows 95, which applies today, extensions are listed against an virtual filetype. Programs are listed against the filetype. This allows you to assign multiple extension to a filetype. You assign programs to the filetype.

This works whereas your suggestion would have unintended consequences. EG: Assigning do* to MS Word will be weird. If you click .dot you expect a new document based on that template. If you click .doc you expect it to open the file.

PS for compatibility reasons you can still list programs against extensions.

```
assoc  | Findstr /c:.doc
```

In response to the comment in other answer. Type `reg /?`. EG `reg query HKCR /f .doc /c /s` but it will be slow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it might be that you missunderstood my question. I don't wont to assign wildcard to filetypes, I just want to search the existing associations using wildcards so I get sort of "filtered results".

Comment: `assoc  | Findstr /c:.doc`

Comment: I figured there was some kind of piping you could use, just couldn't warp my head around it - brain freeze I guess, good thing that superuser exists, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question!

Since file type associations are specified in the Registry at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\`, I created a new key, `.00*`, and set the association default action to be open with 7-Zip. Though the asterisk wild card, `.*`, *does* work on its own to add an association to *all* file types, it did *not* work, in my brief test, when used for the last characters.

[image: Attempted file association with wild card]

So it appears that each file extension needs its own association key.

Sorry about that negative answer.

Comment: thanks, I was hoping s.o. has a script solution or some other out of the box idea that could be combined with `assoc`...  I'll give it a few more days, maybe I'll get lucky... thanks for your help anyway! I'm just thinking, maybe I could use a 3rd party tool for wild card search in the registry.

Comment: In theory, one could write a shell extension based on HKCR\\* and filter the results themselves but I know of no such extension.  Wouldn't be difficult to implement but nobody has cared to write one thus far.